# Testing Telerik UI for WPF controls using QTP/UFT

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, telerik

We are in the initial stages of testing Telerik controls using UFT/QTP. We used Telerik UI for WPF Sample Application
Using the sample application, we tried identifying certain controls. But we found that some of the properties that we used to identify VB 6.0 controls are not working properly when it comes to the identification of WPF controls. Following are some examples to explain the situation better (We used both UFT 12.0 and 11.53 )

- Treeview control

We use 'Select' method followed by the item to be selected from the treeview to select an item in a VB 6.0 control.
    But for WPF control, we need to pass the node number instead of the item name that has to be selected. 
     WpfWindow("WPF Controls Examples").WpfTreeView("explorerTree").Select 0   'To select the first item in the treeview. 
     On passing the item name, UFT is throwing error.

- ListView control

  Several properties that we use to manipulate a List box VB 6.0 control are not working with WPF controls.
   For example, properties lke GetItem, GetSelection, Select, SelectRange etc are throwing an error from UFT/QTP.
   Since 'Select' doesn't select the item in the list box, we need to go with a crude way to do the job. 
   WpfWindow("WPF Controls Examples").WpfList("WpfList").Object.SelectedIndex = 1

Answer (score 1):

As Far As I Know and I use QTP 11 only. HP still don't provide proper support with WPF Controls. In some Cases I've seen people contacting HP and then getting some specific patch, I have not done it so can't comment on that.

What I read and used and understood... If it is WPF and there is a QTP as a tool for automation, be ready to say NO or be ready for limited automation and some sporadic behaviors of controls with QTP or vice a versa.

Answer (score 0):

I am working right now on a project using UFT 12.0 that is testing against wpf/Telerik/custom telerik controls. We are having great success with descriptive programing. On the tree view have you tried getting the child objects for the tree view then clicking the child object you want? One of the guys here solved the tree view problem but he is not here so I can't say exactly how he did it. I am right now trying to solve another problem where I want to close a tab. When UFT opens the tab, then UFT can't see the close button. If I open the tab manually then UFT can see the tab close button and close the tab. Anyway, good luck on your problem.